# Setting the app icon of a Mac osx app in Xcode 2.5

Tags: xcode

This has been bugging me for a while. Xcode 2.5 handles icons differently from later versions of Xcode so there is no Xassets file. Does anyone know how to set the app icon?

Comment: Xcode 2.5? Latest Xcode is Xcode 8.0

Comment: I realize that. And I am running it on a different computer. Lets just say that I have my reasons for wanting to do something in 2.5

Comment: Dude Xcode 2.5 is obsolete and what is the IOS target of your application?

Comment: It's for an old power pc Mac osx app. Look I know 2.5 is obsolete. That's why I'm asking. Because it is quite hard to find documentation on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add high resolution icon. Now, if you want to target only iOS 7, you just need 76 x 76, 120 x 120 and 152 x 152 icon sizes. If you also want to target iOS 6, you’ll need 57 x 57, 72 x 72, 76 x 76, 114 x 114, 120 x 120, 144 x 144 and 152 x 152 icon sizes. Below is the detailed description how to add the same.

[image]

Then add all of them as

[image]

Below is the list of icon dimensions.

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not really. As I said before. This is for Xcode 2.5. Xcode 2.5 does not do iOS. I'm trying to work on a power pc Mac osx app

Comment: Ok, let me check how to add in PC Mac

Comment: Very well, Xcode 2.5-3 was in the year 2007. I suppose i don't have detail idea for that. This URL might help? http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/xcode-2-5-3-changing-application-icon.564480/

Comment: Great Man, Please accept the answer then :) Happy coding